# How to find the correct replacement glass dome for a light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

My wife and I were cleaning the glass dome for our kitchen's main overhead light fixture and it broke.  How do we go about finding a matching replacement?

The electrical and structural metal parts are fine, we just need the glass part.  Would a manufacturer's code be etched on the metal parts somewhere?  Do we need to contact the original builder?

I wish I had a picture (I'm at work at the moment), but the dome was basically the bottom third of a glass sphere, like a shallow bowl, with several holes to attach metal supports.  Nothing terribly fancy, but I have no idea where to look for a matching replacement.

Comment: There are so many entities manufacturing lamps, all over the world, that getting an exact replacement from the original manufacturer is unlikely. If there are more than one fixture and they have to match, prepare yourself for the likelihood of buying more than one replacement so they will match. Supplier endorsement is out of scope here, but an internet search will give you plenty of sourcing options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### See if the globe is a standard/common design.

There are a few "standard" designs for how globes/domes/shades attach to the lamp fixture.  Many manufacturers intentionally build to the standard, and there is a huge aftermarket of various styles of globe, specifically for replacement or "style upgrade" in any compatible fixture.  A lighting distributor or *real* hardware store will have these.  Big-box chain stores maybe not so much.

#### Contact manufacturer

Part number is probably on a sticker on the fixture itself, usually around where the light bulbs are or on the back. You may have to take the fixture down to be able to see this (and if you do, be sure to turn the power off).

Just a warning: It's possible they don't sell the individual part, don't make it anymore, or want to charge more for the part and/or shipping than other options (below).

#### Buy an identical fixture

Find the same fixture somewhere, and use the parts from it you need

#### Just replace the fixture with something better

If you can't find a matching fixture, just replace it with something else.

You can also just use this as an excuse to replace it with something you like better anyway.

Comment: To your thoughtful answer, I added a section discussing how many globes/shades/domes are built to a standard design. I once saw a historic railway car with twenty 1920-era light fixtures.  I asked how on Earth they had a perfect matched set of globes, they said the local Ace Hardware sells them.

Comment: 1 and 2 are an exercise for the homeowner. If you call me I'm doing 3 or 4, done in an hour, no questions asked. +1